# Publicar Django en Apache

Tags: python, django, apache2

alguien quiza me podria explicar como puedo poner a produccion un proyecto de Django con apache, ando un poco perdido .
[Documentacion Oficial Produccion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/howto/deployment/)
he leido la documentacion de django pero la verdad no es clara en cuanto a esto, agradeceria cualquier sugerencia o ayuda..!!

Comment: esta instalacion se hace un mix entre apache y python y django (por el virtualenv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes instalar el modulo wsgi en apache2

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Una vez instalado, debes modificar tu virtualhost y agregar las siguientes lineas:

**WSGIDaemonProcess** : sirve para señalar donde esta tu venv

**WSGIProcessGroup**  : especifica cual es el proceso

**WSGIScriptAlias** : es el equivalente al Alias

---

Suponiendo que tu proyecto se llama **api** y lo instalaste con el usuario **ubuntu**, tu virtualhost debe quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@ejemplo.com
     ServerName ejemplo.com
     ServerAlias www.ejemplo.com

     WSGIDaemonProcess api python-home=/home/ubuntu/api/venv/ python-path=/home/ubuntu/api
     WSGIProcessGroup api
     WSGIPassAuthorization On
     WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/api/wsgi.py
     <Directory /home/ubuntu/api>
        <Files wsgi.py>
           Require all granted
        </Files>
     </Directory>
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_python.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_python.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

El siguiente codigo es para darle permisos al archivo

```
   <Files wsgi.py>
       Require all granted
    </Files>
```

Por ultimo debes reiniciar apache2 (estoy asumiendo que el virtualhost se encontraba)

Comment: muchas gracias..!!

Comment: hace unos meses tuve este dolor de cabeza , y al fin comprendi porque cuando instalamos django esta el archivo wsgi.py , de hecho esto es valido para Flask