# ¿Como utilizar el admin de django en producción y por qué me aparece código en producción? Estoy utilizando FileZilla

Tags: html, python, css, django, django-forms

```
<div class="signin-form" style="background: #D8FCC5; opacity: 0.9;" >
        <div id="alerts">
            {% if messages %}
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                        <strong>Error!</strong> {{ message }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}

            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- Form -->
        <form method="post" id="signin-form_id">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="signin-text">
                <span style="background: #D8FCC5; vertical-align: inherit;">Iniciar sesión en su cuenta</span>
            </div> <!-- / .signin-text -->
```

Esto es lo que me aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Publicar Django en Apache](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/213025/publicar-django-en-apache)

Comment: Tiene pinta de que tu servidor django está enviando directamente el template, sin preprocesar (_renderizar_). O tal vez es el servidor web estático (suponiendo que tengas uno haciendo de proxy reverso) el que está accediendo al template porque no tienes correctamente configurada la redirección hacia el backend django.

Comment: Entonces como hago esa configuracion @abulafia

Comment: @tatianahernandez Eso ya sería otra pregunta, y deberías especificar en ella toda la información relevante. ¿Qué software usas como proxy? ¿nginx, apache? ¿Cómo lanzas la aplicación django? ¿en qué puerto escucha? ¿En qué ruta se monta? A lo mejor, antes de que hagas la pregunta, puedes encontrar respuesta en [alguno de los articulos](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-django/index.html) que hay sobre el tema.

Answer (score 0):

Debes ser mas especifico y detallado con tu pregunta para poder ayudarte.

Puedes crear un archivo que diga settings_production.py y al momento de correr la aplicación `python manage.py runserver --settings=app.settings_production`, puede ser muy fastidioso, también tienes que modificar varias partes como en la url.py principal sobre los archivos media y static.

Esto es un ejemplo: Si tienes una settings_production.py

```
from settings import *
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/tuUsuario/tuapp/recursos/tos/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/tuUsuario/tuapp/recursos/tos/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

DATABASES = {
       default: {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg',
           'NAME': 'name',
           'USER': 'user',
           'PASSWORD': 'pass',
           'HOST': 'localhost';
            }
        } # Depende cual es tu BD
```

en urls.py tendrías:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
             URLS DEL PROYECTO
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Pero que modificaciones se les hace a las url

Comment: @tatianahernandez he editado la respuesta. Una pregunta. Estas practicando como levantar un servidor o es un servidor de producción ya?

Comment: Es un servidor de producción @Jeanpierre Rivas y estoy utilizando FileZilla

Comment: Te puedo ayudar en esto, pero tendría que preguntarte varias cosas y esto sería más como un chat que comentarios simples. Como escribe @abulafia debemos saber más cosas. Si estás interesada me puedes escribir al correo y conversar por hangout. Para mi experiencia ha sido difícil subir un proyecto por primera vez. Mucha suerte. 

E-mail: jeanpierrers1995@gmail.com