# Poner en producción proyecto Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, apache2, deployment

Estoy trabajando con Python 3.5, Django 1.15, Apache2, quiero ponerlo en producción pero cuando sigo los pasos, de [este ejemplo](https://coderwall.com/p/ooerda/python-django-apache-ubuntu), pero me sale este error:

> Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed for
>   '/var/www/env/lib/python3.5/site-packeges:/var/www/env/lib/python3.5'.
>   [Wed Feb 27 15:48:11.615700 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 244:tid
>   139942963824384] mod_wsgi (pid=244): Call to 'site.addsitedir()'
>   failed for '(null)', stopping. [Wed Feb 27 15:48:11.615731 2019]
>   [wsgi:error] [pid 244:tid 139942963824384] mod_wsgi (pid=244): Call to
>   'site.addsitedir()' failed for
>   '/var/www/env/lib/python3.5/site-packeges:/var/www/env/lib/python3.5'.
>   [Wed Feb 27 15:48:11.627686 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 244:tid
>   139942963824384] [remote 192.168.0.3:56840] mod_wsgi (pid=244): Target
>   WSGI script '/var/www/Sistema/Sistema/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as
>   Python module. [Wed Feb 27 15:48:11.627722 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid
>   244:tid 139942963824384] [remote 192.168.0.3:56840] mod_wsgi
>   (pid=244): Exception occurred processing WSGI script
>   '/var/www/Sistema/Sistema/wsgi.py'. [Wed Feb 27 15:48:11.627888 2019]
>   [wsgi:error] [pid 244:tid 139942963824384] [remote 192.168.0.3:56840]
>   Traceback (most recent call last): [Wed Feb 27 15:48:11.627906 2019]
>   [wsgi:error] [pid 244:tid 139942963824384] [remote 192.168.0.3:56840] 
>   File "/var/www/Sistema/Sistema/wsgi.py", line 12, in  [Wed Feb
>   27 15:48:11.627917 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 244:tid 139942963824384]
>   [remote 192.168.0.3:56840]     from django.core.wsgi import
>   get_wsgi_application [Wed Feb 27 15:48:11.627930 2019] [wsgi:error]
>   [pid 244:tid 139942963824384] [remote 192.168.0.3:56840] ImportError:
>   No module named 'django'

Tengo esto en el archivo de configuración de Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dumny-host.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www
ServerName servicios.x.x.x.x
ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/logs/acces.log combined
WSGIDaemonProcess SystemProyect processes=5 python-path=/var/www/Sistema:/var/www/env/lib/python3.5/site-packeges:/var/www/env/lib/python3.5 threads=1
WSGIProcessGroup SystemProyect
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Sistema/Sistema/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/213025/publicar-django-en-apache

Comment: @DiegoAvila me levanto el servidor ok, pero no funcionan los javassript y css hay que poner algo mas para que el apache los reconozca

Comment: debes agregar: Alias /static path/MIproyecto/static..algo como eso

Comment: no te olvides de ejecutar: python manage.py collectstatic

Comment: mas detalle aca: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te falta los archivos js o css, tienes que agregar el sgte código. a tus

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
REPOSITORY_ROOT = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(REPOSITORY_ROOT, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(REPOSITORY_ROOT, 'media/')
```

Luego en la `url.py` del proyecto:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
....urls......
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```