# Django rediceccionar http a https

Tags: django, http, https

estoy intentando redireccionar una peticion http a https, lo estoy probando en local y me da el siguiente fallo:

```
SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

Y en la consola me dice:

```
code 400, message Bad request version ('¶ÆO_)\x83\x97þ°hò\xad\x8f\x8a\x92gÎ¿|~°OFðJV;\x8d\x83nlj\x00$\x13\x01\x13\x03\x13\x02À+À/Ì©Ì¨À,À0À')
You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

En settings tengo lo siguiente:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 1
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

No se si lo estoy poniendo mal o tengo que implementarlo con Nginx

Este es mi nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name server;

  # ssl    on; Deprecated
  ssl_session_timeout  5m;
  ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/lab01.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/lab01.key;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

  location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://server/;
  }

  location /login {
      return 301 /;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass          http://server/;
    proxy_read_timeout  20d;
    proxy_buffering off;

    proxy_redirect      http://server/ $scheme://$host/;
  }

  location /dashboard {
    return 301 /;
  }
```

}

Si alguien tiene alguna idea os lo agradezco.

Comment: no es mejor hacer el redireccionamiento en tu vhost con nginx?

Comment: lo de la redirección a https es mejor gestionarla con nginx y usar gunicorn como servidor para producción.

Comment: Hay que gestionarla en ambos lados. Respecto a Gunicorn no lo recomiendo. uWSGI es el ideal para producción, pues es el más potente.

Comment: Gracias, probare a configurarlo desde nginx

Comment: realice una respuesta con [apache2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/213025/publicar-django-en-apache) puede que te sirva para nginx

Answer (score 0):

Si lo estas probando en local con el servidor integrado de Django no puedes hacerlo ya que como te dice el error únicamente soporta HTTP y no HTTPS.

Tu configuración en Django es correcta, pero debes configurar nginx también para que te haga la redirección:

```
# Si entramos por el protocolo HTTP redirigimos a HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name tuweb.com www.tuweb.com;
    return 301 https://tuweb.com$request_uri;
}
```

Tras tu edición adjuntando el `nginx.conf`, la configuración sería:

```
# Si entramos por el protocolo HTTP redirigimos a HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name server;
    return 301 https://server$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name server;

  # ssl    on; Deprecated
  ssl_session_timeout  5m;
  ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/lab01.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/lab01.key;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

  location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://server/;
  }

  location /login {
      return 301 /;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass          http://server/;
    proxy_read_timeout  20d;
    proxy_buffering off;

    proxy_redirect      http://server/ $scheme://$host/;
  }

  location /dashboard {
    return 301 /;
  }
}
```

Donde `server` asignado a `server_name` seria tu dominio o IP al igual que para `proxy_pass` y demás variables similares.

Comment: Buenas, en mi archivo de nginx.conf tengo otro server { ... }
¿Puedo tener varios?

Comment: Puedes tener varios, pero ojo, no pises mismas configuraciones. Adjunta tu nginx.conf

Comment: Ahi lo tienes.
He probado a ponerlo dentro pero cuando navego es como si se liara o no encuentra la ruta y va al inicio